# Найти разницу между максимальным и минимальным элементами массива

Tags: java, массивы, вывод, max, min

Написала код, который должен найти разницу между max и min элементами массива. Код запускается без ошибки, но нету самого результата, то есть не выводится число. Помогите понять ошибку.

```java
public class Lab4_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {2, 5, 7, 8, 3, 0};
    }

    public static int range(int[] array, int index, int min, int max) {
        if (index == array.length) {
            if (index == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return max - min;
        } else {
            int value = array[index];
            return range(array, index + 1, Math.min(value, min), Math.max(value, max));
        }
    }

    public static int range(int[] array) {
        return range(array, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если запустить код, действительно ничего не произойдет. У вас нигде нет строчки

```
System.out.println();
```

Вообще я не очень понимаю, зачем вам два переопределенных метода.

Мое решение всей проблемы сразу в main

```
    int[] array = {2, 5, 7, 8, 3, 0};
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println(array[array.length - 1] - array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код всё равно неправильный, даже если заставить его печатать. Для нахождения разницы между минимумом и максимумом используйте такой метод:

```
public static OptionalInt range(int... array) {
    OptionalInt range = OptionalInt.empty();

    if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
        int min = array[0];
        int max = min;

        for (int n : array) {
            if (n < min) {
                min = n;
            } else if (n > max) {
                max = n;
            }
        }
        range = OptionalInt.of(max - min);
    }

    return range;
}
```

Вызывать его можно двумя способами:

```
int[] arr = {2, 4, 6, 8};
OptionalInt range = range(arr);
```

или

```
OptionalInt range = range(1, 2, 3, 5);
```

Метод возращает `OptionalInt`, а не число, потому что не всегда есть минимум и максимум. Их нет когда массив пустой или когда нет самого массива и метод получил `null`.

Для того, чтобы распечатать `OptionalInt` можно использовать метод `ifPresent()` или, начиная с Java 9, метод `ifPresentOrElse()`. Например:

```
int[] arr = {2, 4, 6, 8};
range(arr).ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println, () -> System.out.println("no range"));

arr = null;
range(arr).ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println, () -> System.out.println("no range"));

arr = new int[0];
range(arr).ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println, () -> System.out.println("no range"));

range(1, 2, 3, 5).ifPresent(System.out::println);

range().ifPresent(System.out::println);     // ничего не напечатает

range(null).ifPresent(System.out::println); // ничего не напечатает
```

Использование сортировки, для нахождения минимума и максимума, менее эффективно.

Comment: Ростислав, зачем все так сложно?

Comment: Что именно сложно, `OptionalInt` и работа с ним? Вместо возврата `OptionalInt.empty()` можно бросать исключение, но тогда вызов этого метода будет ещё сложнее. В любом случае нужно учитывать ситуации, когда минимума и максимума просто нет, а значит и нет разницы между ними. В таком случае вы не можете возвращать какое-то число.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить минимальный и максимальный элемент в массиве `int[]`, можно использовать методы [`IntStream.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--) и [`IntStream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--):

```java
int[] arr = {2, 5, 7, 8, 3, 0};

int max = Arrays.stream(arr).max().getAsInt();
int min = Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsInt();

System.out.println(max - min); // 8
```